# Why would accept address argument be all zeros?

Tags: linux, sockets, osx-yosemite

Using bsd style sockets, I call:

```
accept(listenfd, &address, &len);
```

Up until today, this worked fine.

Starting today, I've been seeing the address structure be all zeros.

In other words, the kernel doesn't know what the ip address of the client is - or at least, it's refusing to tell me that address in this context. This happens both on Linux and OS-X.

Needless to say, I don't see any documentation relevant to this issue on the accept man pages I've reviewed. Nor have my searches for discussion on this topic been finding me anything.

I can find *plenty* of (mostly conflicting) advice on what I should be doing instead. And maybe I'll be taking some of that advice (`getsockname()` looks promising...). But I need to understand what is happening here.

So... why would this be happening? What would have to change, to make `accept()` work as documented in the man page?

Comment: Is `listenfd` an IPv4 or IPv6 socket? What is `address` declared as? Are you initializing `len`? You need to show your actual code.

Comment: IPv4. address is struct sockaddr_storage and the pointer to it is cast to (struct sockaddr *) before being passed to accept. I was not initializing len - that might be my problem.

Comment: yes, thanks that was it - and I see now that I missed the relevant sentence in the man page. This issue in the code is now fixed. (I can point to the code on github, though, if you really want to see it...)

Comment: ["The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer address. "](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept)

Answer (score 0):

Remy pointed at the answer which was relevant for this case.

When calling `accept()`, the third argument to `accept()` needs to be initialized to the byte size of the buffer being passed in the second parameter.